# When should we sleep?

Tags: sleep, sleep-cycles

Is sleeping every day from 4 am to 10 am is equivalent to sleeping from 12 to 6 am at night? Also, what is the best time to go to sleep at night? And how many hours of sleep is necessary for good health? Also is sleeping at daytime like at afternoon is good?

Comment: Not sleeping „normally“ [can lead to sleep disorders](https://www.webmd.com/sleep-disorders/features/night-shift-sleep), [here‘s a more elaborate Times article](http://time.com/3183183/best-time-to-sleep/). Don’t have time to turn this into an answer, anyone’s free to do that!

Answer (score 1):

It's best to choose the time period for sleeping such that [it doesn't need to be changed often](https://www.webmd.com/sleep-disorders/tc/shift-work-sleep-disorder-topic-overview#1), as this leads to better sleep quality. If this means that you need to sleep during daytime, then you need to make sure your bedroom is very dark and soundproof (or you need to use earplugs).

Note also that the official time is based on arbitrary decisions, e.g. in China they only have one time zone even though the Sun will rise 5 hours later in the far West of the country compared to the Eastern part.